# Calculating max concurrent "User Logins" using LINQ and DateTime objects

Tags: c#, linq

I am having trouble coming up with a proper way to create a query under the following scenario:

I want to find the maximum amount of "users" logged into a hypothetical system at any given point.  If, throughout a given period of time, the most peopled logged in at the same time was 5, my query should return 5.

I am using LINQ and would consider myself a beginner; this is the most advanced query I have attempted.

My users are stored in a Database table described like User_Logged_In_Table(user_id, begin_date_time, end_date_time).  User_ID is an integer, and begin_date_time and end_date_time are DateTime C# objects.

My current understanding takes me about this far:

```
myFunction(begin_time, end_time) //<- These two variables represent the threshold of time I am querying about.
{
    var u = from users in database.User_Logged_In_Tables
            where (users.begin_date_time.CompareTo(begin_time) > 0)
                  && (users.begin_date_time.CompareTo(end_time) < 0)
            select users;

            //The above tells me the users who have been logged in between those two times
            //however it does not tell me anything about their concurrency.
}
```

I am stuck at this point, unsure of how to continue the query with what I need.

Any hints, or suggestions are much appreciated!  Also I am willing to further explain my situation if I have been unclear in any area.

Comment: The stupid answer would be to query against each minute from your interval and see how many users you get, but then again... there must be a better answer.

Comment: Vladislav, thank you for your comment!  That could possibly work, I will keep your suggestion in mind.  I feel as if LINQ should be able to handle it a little better though, without the use of my own forloops and record keeping.  Maybe I am dreaming and will have to do the grunt work with code outside of LINQ :D We will see. Thank you again.

Comment: don't be afraid to go outside of LINQ if you must. Just look for the prettiest solution (I really mean pretty, as in "looks good").

Comment: If you have users.begin_date_time.CompareTo(begin_time) > 0, what about those users who logged in before your threshold period, but logged off during or after?

Comment: Miika, thank you for your comment! Any user who logged in before the threshold is not counted by choice.  A user who may log out after the threshold may or may not be counted also by choice. Theorethically, these are extra stipulations I may handle at a later time. Well noted, however, as it is true that these users who fall under these conditions would not be counted under the current query logic. I appreciate your comment!

Answer (score 0):

So I think I could share this as an answer now. It seems that this is a standard problem, I found something interesting on http://www.haikulabs.com/Schedu10.htm. Basically, your "reservations" are your log-in sessions and your "rooms" are your HTTP connections.

To find the minimum number of connections to handle your users (so, max concurrent users), you would need to test against a DateTime in a for loop and `.AddMinutes` or `.AddHours` depending on the resolution you want.

Now, the above won't be accurate - it's possible that there's a short session right between the values you are testing and you'll miss it. So to make it 100% accurate, you need to test against all DateTimes where a session has either started or ended and not against every round minute or every round hour.

Comment: I have attempted this approach, and feel I have made some headway. Thank you very much for your response! I will post a solution if I get it functional.

Comment: @mherr and thank you for the question, I found it really interesting to think about it :) Haha I even got my father involved (he contributed the last paragraph).

Comment: Strange how a question on a forum can initiate so much conversation between family and strangers :) I am very glad to have made my post, give your father my thanks as well!

Answer (score 0):

"Any given period of time" is vague, so you'll have to lock it down, like by saying you will look at each **minute** of time in between the start param and the end param, and you will take the average number of concurrernt logins among those minutes to determine the "overall" average.

So now, you'll initialize a list of ints, then loop thru the param start time, adding a mintute for each loop, until you are at the max. Inside that loop, you'll look for distinct logins that have either started in that minute, or are still continuing in that minute. You will grab the Distinct() user_ids (so that one user logging in twice within 5 seconds still counts as 1 login) and you will add that distinct count to the list of int.

At the end, you'll have a list of int that's as long as the number of minutes in between startTime and endTime, and that list can be called with Average() to see the average number of logins for each given minute.

Comment: Well this is basically what I suggested and it won't be accurate. Look at the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: I have attempted this approach, and feel I have made some headway. Thank you very much for your response! I will post a solution if I get it functional.

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions for querying based on discrete time intervals is good, I have used the same method in some of my own work applications.

However, one thing to note is that the number of concurrent users only changes when a user logs in or out. Moreover, the number of concurrent users only increases when the user logs in (Sorry for obvious comment, but trying to make sure I have this clear in my own mind too). So it should be sufficient to create a LINQ query that goes over each user found by your initial search (with the range restriction), and checking how many users are logged in at each "login time", and taking the maximum number from this. Actual LINQ below (The code below is in VB.Net, and using my own field names as that is what I had to test with, my apologies if this is a problem):

Firstly, to get a list of concurrent users at each login point we have:

```
Dim listOfConcurrent =
    From row As DataRow In userRange
    Select New hlxListItem(Of DateTime)(
        row.Field(Of DateTime)("CiDateStart"),
        (From subRow In userRange
        Where subRow.Field(Of DateTime)("CiDateStart") <=
                row.Field(Of DateTime)("CiDateStart") AndAlso
            subRow.Field(Of DateTime)("CiDateEnd") > row.Field(Of DateTime)("CiDateStart")
        Select subRow).Count)
```

Alternatively, you can get the "hlxListItem" with the highest number to get max concurrent users:

```
Dim maxConcurrent =
    (From row As DataRow In userRange
    Order By (From subRow In userRange
        Where subRow.Field(Of DateTime)("CiDateStart") <=
                row.Field(Of DateTime)("CiDateStart") AndAlso
            subRow.Field(Of DateTime)("CiDateEnd") > row.Field(Of DateTime)("CiDateStart")
        Select subRow).Count Descending
    Select New hlxListItem(Of DateTime)(
        row.Field(Of DateTime)("CiDateStart"),
        (From subRow In userRange
        Where subRow.Field(Of DateTime)("CiDateStart") <=
                row.Field(Of DateTime)("CiDateStart") AndAlso
            subRow.Field(Of DateTime)("CiDateEnd") > row.Field(Of DateTime)("CiDateStart")
        Select subRow).Count)).First()
```

So, finally just some notes on the above. hlxListItem is just a simple object with a generic field, and a text field. The generic in this case holds the date (login time) and the text field holds the number of concurrent users. If I have time, I can try to edit the above examples into C# and to using your field names, but I posted the above because I could confirm that it works. Let me know if the above helps you out, or if you need any additional help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough explanation and code example! You have a very good point, about only checking how many users are on during a login, as opposed to every single minute.  That would reduce cycles very considerably.  Thus far I have tried to implement the approach the other two gentlemen were kind enough to post, I may continue with that until I give up.  I am using linq in c#, so it may take me some time to parse your code example, but thank you for posting!  I tried to upvote all three of you guys but I don't have enough reputation doh >.>

Comment: @mherr It should be fairly simple to convert to C#. Just the Field(Of DateTime) to Field<DateTime> and then plug in your own field names (and use whatever you want to replace the hlxListItem, even an anonymous type).